# Does WP Super Cache Timestamps test result matter?

Tags: wordpress, caching

In WP Super Cache setting page, if I click on the Test cache button with Cloudflare HTML minification checked I will receive the result:
"The pages do not match! Timestamps differ or were not found!"

And if Cloudflare HTML minification unchecked then the test result is OK for everything.

So which of the following is right:

**This test result is for "testing" purpose only, it wont affect anything and WP Super Cache is going to work anyhow.**

or

**The result will determine if WP Super cache is going to work or not.**

Somehow I need HTML minification and WP Super Cache work together, I have around 1M of pageviews daily, so saving a couple tenth of bytes would be something right?

Adding some justification about either one of these would be greatly appreciated.